# Ditto call excludes docs by template-variable

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution, ditto

I want to exclude all docs in my Ditto call that have a certain template-variable... say `tv-1` with a value. Well, it doesnt matter if the TV has a value or not. Just the presence of the TV applied to a specific resource document would already be enough to exclude it.
On second thought, the exclusion by "template", for example `TPLcourse` would also work.

Is that possible?

Currently my working Ditto call is following:

```
[[Ditto? 
&id=`siblings`
&parents=`[*parent*]`
&filter=`id,[*id*],2`
&depth=`1`
&tpl=`read-more`
&paginate=`1`
&display=`1`
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter by template you just have to extend the &filter property.

```
&filter=`id,[*id*],2|template,5,1`
```

The second filter part will filter away all resources that don't have the template 5.

Comment: I tried that before but didnt work... in my case it would be this right? ... `&filter=`id,[*id*],2|TPLcourse,5,1` and then ´5` would be the ID number of the template TPLcourse, right?